# Why are npm install && npm install <pack-name> both required?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

Why do we need both `npm install` and `npm install base1` in the `prestart` section?

If `npm install` itself retrieves `base1` from Git then why do we need to mention `npm install base1` in `prestart`?

For one Node.js program I saw the `package.json` shown here:

```
{
  "name": "user01",
  "version": "1.5.1",
  "description": "",
  "author": "",
  "private": "true",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js",
    "prestart": "npm install && npm install base1 && npm install base2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "ain2": "*",
    "body-parser": "^1.15.0",
    "express": "^4.13.3",
    "uuid": "*",
    "request": "^2.69.0",
    "traverse": "*",
    "base1": "git+ssh://xxxxxxxxxxx/base1.git",
    "base2": "git+ssh://xxxxxxxxxx/base2.git"
  }
}
```

Comment: Are `base1` and `base2` available on your npm registry?

Comment: No base1 &  base2 are module written by other team, which is checked in git. so pulling it using git url

Comment: ah nevermind.. it looks like if the package is listed in package.json, `npm` knows to look at the local definition first.

Answer (score 0):

The first run is to get the packages, the second is to basically initialize them.

npm install

> `npm install` (in package directory, no arguments):
>
> Install the dependencies in the local node_modules folder.

npm install package

> `npm install <folder>`:
>
> Install a package that is sitting in a folder on the filesystem.

Source: [NPMJS](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install)

Comment: `base1` and `base2` would be installed to `node_modules/base[12]` from npms frame of reference (wherever the `package.json` sits).

Comment: npm install itself installing base1 and base2 in node_modules. Then what extra this npm install base1 will do?

Answer (score 0):

The extra commands might do nothing in npm@3 or recent versions of npm@2 where the git remote is fetched every time. They could be a workaround for some [previous git issues](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/1727) where code doesn't update to the latest commit on `npm install` (back in v0.12 releases). Specifying the package could force the fetch of the latest version of the code from git, which a plain `npm install` wouldn't do when the package was already installed.

To confirm what currently happens, see what the differences are for the git `base1` package.

```
rm -rf node_modules/base1
npm install -d

rm -rf node_modules/base1    
npm install -d base1

rm -rf node_modules/base1
npm install -d
npm install -d base1
```

When the code in git has been updated run the two installs in debug without removing the modules

```
npm install -d
npm install -d base1
```

The extra installs are probably not required any more, if this was their purpose.

Comment: Hi Matt, Thanks for explanation. But how my package.json should be for not fetching the git modules every time & only required for first time and some update happens

Comment: I don't think that's possible at the moment. It seems the workaround of npm fetching the remote each time remains. The fetch is pretty quick as it just needs to confirm that the local copy is up to date with the remote repo, rather than downloading everything.